# Docker container log file missing

Tags: docker, logging, centos, docker-daemon

On running the command `docker container ps -a | grep my_app` the docker is showing that its in running status, but the moment I try to see the logs using `docker logs -f 858509fc385f` where **858509fc385f** is the container_id for my_app container. It gives the following error :-

```
Error grabbing logs: open /var/lib/docker/containers/858509fc385f5ea264f7fd729d9bab32a99742cd0743dc253dcf8a3967ad195c/858509fc385f5ea264f7fd729d9bab32a99742cd0743dc253dcf8a3967ad195c-json.log: no such file or directory
```

The host machine is **CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810**.

The docker version details are :-
[image]

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which image do you use?

Comment: @Mustafa Its Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: What is your default logging driver ? could you run `docker info --format '{{.LoggingDriver}}'` and share the output ?